# MongoDB returns "I ACCESS [conn6] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { find: "user", filter: { username: "root" } }"

Tags: mongodb, vert.x

I followed the illustration of vertx's mongo auth like this:

```
MongoClient client = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject().put("connection_string", "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin"), "My Pool");
    JsonObject authProperties = new JsonObject()
            .put("username", "root")
            .put("password", "root");

    MongoAuth authProvider = MongoAuth.create(client, authProperties);
```

And i've created a user, which has been named of "root", on my local MongoDB Server:

```
 db.getUser("root");
```

{
        "_id" : "admin.root",
        "user" : "root",
        "db" : "admin",
        "customData" : {
                "user" : "XXX"
        },
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "admin"
                },
                {
                        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}

But when i ran this verticle, it did noting but print the following:
**: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out**

The log of MongoDB(the latest version) server:

**2017-04-13T15:30:45.373+0800 I ACCESS   [conn6] Unauthorized: not authorized on admin to execute command { find: "user", filter: { username: "root" } }**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just load the connection configs from a json config file.

```
JsonObject mongoConfig = Config.getObject("mongo_config");
MongoClient mongo = MongoClient.createShared(vertx, mongoConfig);
```

Config file:

```
{
    "mongo_config":{
     "db_name":"somedb",
     "connection_string":"mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me more detail code ?  does your mongo use " "SCRAM-SHA-1" or "MONGODB-CR" authentication?

Comment: Its `SCRAM-SHA-1`